# Hardhat Tasks - How to import an account with a private key as signer

Tags: hardhat, accounts, private-key

I am writing a Hardhat task. Hardhat ethers provides `ethers.getSigners()`which returns me the addresses derived from the mnemonics saved in `process.env`.

However, I want to use an account address, of which I have the private key only and would like to import that account, use it as signers for the contract calls and get the address.

How can I achieve that?

In the task, currently `signers[0]`is used as signer. How could I switch to `signers[1]`?

Comment: you can use accounts instead of mnemonics e.x. accounts: [privateKey1, privateKey2, ...] check this https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config

Answer (score 0):

this works for me using ethers.js

```
import { Signer, Wallet } from 'ethers';
        
const provider = hre.ethers.provider;
const privKey = process.env['PRIVATE_KEY'];
const signer_wallet = new Wallet(privKey);
const signer = await signer_wallet.connect(provider);
```

Once you have your signer you can use it to deploy contracts or connect to existing ones

Answer (score 0):

Update your `hardhat.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/<key>",
      accounts: [private_key, private_key,...] // compatible with your `signers[0], signers[1]`
    }
  },
 ...
}
```